# Match key order of a dictionary with respect to another dictionary python

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries

```
foo = {'PP001': 14, 'PS001': 14, 'PL001': 14, 'FIN1151A': 22, 'FSS001': 54, 'FIN1198A': 18, 
       'CRT6423': 8, 'CIN1198C': 24, 'CSS001': 32}

bar = {'FSS001': 50, 'FIN1151A': 22, 'PL001': 14, 'PS001': 14, 'PP001': 14, 'FIN1198A': 18, 
       'CSS001': 19, 'CIN1198C': 24, 'CRT6423': 8}
```

I want the key order of second dictionary same as of the first one.

How can I do that?

Comment: `bar = {key: bar[key] for key in foo.keys()}`

Comment: Do note that only relatively recent Python versions keep order within dicts at all…

Comment: Hi Rahul, as far as I know the dictionaries in Python are not meant to be ordered

Comment: Try using the OrderedDict in Python. An OrderedDict is a dictionary subclass that remembers the order that keys were first inserted.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop in Python >=3.7 dictionaries are now guaranteed to maintain insertion order. Or if you don’t trust that use OrderedDict.